# How to take some part of image out of container

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a requirement to place an image at the end of layout, and it will be 20% out of the screen boundary, I am unable to find out any way to achieve this, the only possible way is to set image view width to 1000dp, the some part of image is out of the screen, but this does not seem to be a valid approach

I want to achieve something like following.

[image]

Comment: have you tried android:layout_marginRight="-20dp" ?

Comment: @AntonisRadz : This works on textview, but its not effecting imageView

Comment: it might depend on a  parent layout that you are using

Comment: try using Guide Line in constraint layout.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Horizontal/vertical bias in ConstraintLayout. Something like:

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In above example imageview is cropped 20% from right